# Controller.Json method encodes & to \u0026

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I am creating an array of URLs and in my controller, using Controller.Json(array) to return the JsonResult back to a client. However one of the urls has "&" character. This character is getting encoded to \u0026. When I open this URL in the browser, the browser DOESNT interpret this as "&" character.

example: http://myserver.com/Controller/Action?id=1234\u0026lang=ENG

This doesnot lead to my controller action: Action(int id);

How can i decode this back to &. Any ideas would be useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/), `\u0026` is a valid part of a string, and represents the `&` character.

If whatever you are using to deserialise the JSON doesn't turn `\u0026` back into `&`, then it's doing it wrong. You should use something that can deserialise it correctly, and not try to fix it after it is already broken.

Comment: I am not deserializing anywhere. Its just a URL and I am trying to hit the URL using my browser. Where do I need to deserialise?

Comment: @letsc: If you are just picking the string out of the JSON text, then you get the encoded string. You need to decode the JSON as usual to get the actual string where the escaped characters are converted back into the original form.